# Oracle JSON_ARRAYAGG with Limit/Rownum based on ORDER BY

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, oracle19c

I'm using Oracle 19c and the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function (with `JSON_OBJECT`) to return a concatenated array string of JSON objects. I need to **limit the result to top 10 objects based on the ORDER BY SENT_DATE DESC**.

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG` has its own `ORDER BY` so that's where I put it. However, is there a Limit facility?

The following is syntactically correct, but the results are incorrect. My JSON objects are not in SENT_DATE DESC order in the concatenated string.

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object('sentDate' value mh.sent_date, 
                                 'sentByEmail' value mh.send_by_email,  
                                 'sentBy' value mh.sent_by, 
                                 'sentByName' value mh.sent_by_name,  
                                 'sentToEmail' value mh.sendee_email)  
                                 ORDER BY mh.sent_date DESC) /*ORDER BY inside json_arrayagg)*/
                                                             /*Normally this works, but not with ROWNUM*/
    from mail_history_t mh 
    where mh.plan_id = 763 and mh.is_current_status = 'Y' and rownum <= 10; /*ROWNUM outside*/
```

I see that it's incorrect if I check the top results in my usual row query,

```
select * from mail_history_t where plan_id = 763 and is_current_status ='Y' order by sent_date desc;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the top 10 rows in a subquery first, using the `fetch first` row-limiting clause, then aggregate in the outer query:

```
select json_arrayagg(
    json_object(
        'sentDate'    value sent_date, 
        'sentByEmail' value send_by_email,  
        'sentBy'      value sent_by, 
        'sentByName'  value sent_by_name,  
        'sentToEmail' value sendee_email
    )  
    order by sent_date desc
) js_array
from (
    select *
    from mail_history_t
    where plan_id = 763 and  is_current_status = 'Y'
    order by sent_date desc
    fetch first 10 rows only
) t
```

Comment: Thanks, is the `JSON_AGGARRAY`'s *internal* `ORDER BY` still necessary after this?

Comment: @geneb.: it does a different thing, that is ordering the elements *within the json array* (which is usually a good thing if you want a deterministic results - otherwise the database is free to order the array elements as it likes).